Facing issue with intiating AppsFlyer 6.13.1 Sdk in android
I am starting AppsFlyerLib in my application class like below
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().init(APPS_FLYER_DEB_KEY, null, getApplicationContext());
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().start(getApplicationContext())
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().setDebugLog(true)

I am receiving below exception logs :-

AppsFlyer_6.13.1         E  [HTTP Client] Error while sending request to server: com.appsflyer.internal.components.network.http.exceptions.HttpException: Failed to connect to nbi98e-launches.appsflyersdk.com/:::443
com.appsflyer.internal.components.network.http.exceptions.HttpException: Failed to connect to nbi98e-launches.appsflyersdk.com/:::443
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1sSDK.AFKeystoreWrapper(:121)
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1uSDK.AFInAppEventParameterName(:46)
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFf1rSDK.values(:154)
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1eSDK.AFLogger(:207)
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1fSDK$4.run(:186)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to nbi98e-launches.appsflyersdk.com/:::443
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1sSDK.AFKeystoreWrapper(:84)
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1uSDK.AFInAppEventParameterName(:46) 
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFf1rSDK.values(:154) 
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1eSDK.AFLogger(:207) 
at com.appsflyer.internal.AFe1fSDK$4.run(:186) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 

Is there anything i am doing wrong here?

Looks like an internet problem (Firewall, VPN ,...) or Date (check Time Settings)
